# How to cache in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, caching, symfony

I need to cache some application specific data using Symfony 2's caching system so that I can run `cache:clear` to clear it. All the cache relies under `app/cache` but how do I actually go about caching data?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/index.html

The only topic I see is about HTML caching with Varnish.

Comment: Symfony2 can do this caching internally too with the ESI implementation. It might seem a bit convoluted at first, but it makes the step to scaling with Varnish much smaller.

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeHuberdeau I'm interested in caching app specific data, not template/HTML.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you are using Doctrine already just use those cache classes.

Add a service to `config.yml`:

```
services:
    cache:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache
```

And use it in your controller:

```
if ($fooString = $this->get('cache')->fetch('foo')) {
    $foo = unserialize($fooString);
} else {
    // do the work
    $this->get('cache')->save('foo', serialize($foo));
}
```

Comment: What if I'm not using Doctrine? Why is this part of Doctrine?

Comment: @Tower Still no answer to this?

Comment: @Tower The answer seems to be that Doctrine needed this component, and created a damn good one so Symfony2 is not gonna reinvent it, but they didn't separate it into a different repository, so here we are.

Comment: This is part of Doctrine\Common. Don't confuse this with ORM, DBAL etc. "The Doctrine Common project is a library that provides extensions to core PHP functionality."

Comment: @Tower without use Doctrine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407790/in-symfony-2-is-there-a-good-way-to-interact-with-the-app-cache-cache-using-rea/13410635#13410635

Comment: The Doctrine cache classes are now available via the doctrine/cache package if you use Composer.

Comment: Is there a way for set it a time?

Comment: If you're not using whole Doctrine ORM, you can still install just part `doctrine/cache` https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle which is decoupled from the ORM part of the doctrine

Comment: @FrancisGonzales The `save` method takes a third `lifetime` parameter: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.0/class-Doctrine.Common.Cache.Cache.html

Comment: PS: Doctrine offers a lot of different cache implementations: https://github.com/doctrine/cache/tree/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache

Comment: Hey thank you for your solution I have tow question does The class still the same with symfony4 ? no improvement ? and what command do we need to delete the cache?

Answer (score 33):

Simple way use **Doctrine cache providers**.
At first, register service(sample in *config.yml*):

```
services:
    memcached:
        class: Memcached
        calls:
            - [ addServer, ['localhost', 11211] ]
    memcached_cache:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache
        calls:
            - [ setMemcached, [@memcached] ]
```

Then to use get service, for example in controler:

```
$cache = $this->get('memcached_cache');
```

to send in another service use *calls*:

```
calls:
    - [ setCacheProvider, [@memcached_cache] ]
```

or arguments:

```
arguments:
    - @memcached_cache
```

In the same way, you can use other interfaces of Doctrine Cache package.
Doctrine Cache provides a very simple interface for which several out of the box implementations are provided:

- ApcCache (requires ext/apc)
- ArrayCache (in memory, lifetime of the request)
- FilesystemCache (not optimal for high concurrency)
- MemcacheCache (requires ext/memcache)
- MemcachedCache (requires ext/memcached)
- PhpFileCache (not optimal for high concurrency)
- RedisCache.php (requires ext/phpredis)
- WinCacheCache.php (requires ext/wincache)
- XcacheCache.php (requires ext/xcache)
- ZendDataCache.php (requires Zend Server Platform)

If **you do not already use Doctrine**, you may require **Common Library for Doctrine projects**: `php composer.phar require doctrine/common` or require only **Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends**: `php composer.phar require doctrine/cache`

How to use Doctrine Caching you can read in [Doctrine Common documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/caching.html) on [Doctrine Project web site](http://doctrine-project.org/)

Comment: thank you very much for this answer, it finally works, I just had a little error with YAML, it seems that @memcached require quotes - [ setMemcached, ['@memcached'] ] (I'm using symfony 3.0)

Answer (score 10):

Symfony 3.1 provide a new [Cache component](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-cache-component).

Answer (score 8):

Symfony2 does not provide any component for application layer caching.

Like you were already told, you can use the Doctrine Common caching library http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/caching.html

If you want something more advanced, you can also use one of the cache bundle provided by the community. For instance, the https://github.com/TheBigBrainsCompany/TbbcCacheBundle#cachebundle which provides tools for a good caching strategy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no partial cache in Symfony2, the build-in cache is full HTTP only.
You have to use a reverse proxy, and if you only want to cache a piece of code, you have to use ESI. It's maybe more work than with symfony 1 but performances worth it.

Anyway, nothing stop you to use a memcached and store some stuff in it, look [at this Bundle](http://knpbundles.com/beryllium/CacheBundle) i.e.
If as your question state it, you only have data to store, that's perfect (and a memcache cache is much faster than a filesystem one).

Comment: I'm interested in caching app specific data, like computationally expensive results, etc. I'm already caching them on APC, but what's the point of having 2 different cache systems? I also need to clear two caches now, although I did make one command of my own which clears both, but still.

Comment: It's said APC should not be used for caching data (like from DB) when it's used as opcode cache, because it affects its performance. There's a point why to use separate cache for custom data storing.