# How to cache data in symfony2

Tags: caching, symfony

Is there any built in possibility (or an external bundle) to cache data in Symfony2?

I don't want to cache the page itself, but data inside the application, using a simple key -> value store on the file system for example.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893081/how-to-cache-in-symfony-2

Answer (score 2):

There's no built in solution, but I recommend you giving [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apc.php), [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) a try (they're all in-memory datastores).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LiipDoctrineCacheBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipDoctrineCacheBundle) to integrate cache drivers from Doctrine common into your Symfony project.

Answer (score 1):

i'm using [winzouCacheBundle](https://github.com/winzou/CacheBundle). it gives you a streamlined cache api on different backends (apc,file,memcache,array,xcache, zenddata).

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no unique solution for caching in Symfony2. Some parts of the framework use [Doctrine Common](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html).

There are discussions about a "standard" caching solution if Symfony2, but we will have to wait for some time...

Comment: Now the caching system of doctrine is out of the common https://github.com/doctrine/cache

Answer (score 0):

I think the **DoctrineCacheBundle** is currently the way to go.

> The DoctrineCacheBundle allows your Symfony application to use different caching systems through the Doctrine Cache library.

[Docs @ Symfony.com](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineCacheBundle/index.html)

[Code @ Github](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCacheBundle)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well, you would like to store data (attached to the session) and reload them when the same session will call again a new controller, in order to avoid to execute the same procedure more times (for example to read a table from a database).

You can use the session system in your controllers:

```
<?php
namespace YourStuff\YourBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    $session = $this->get("session");
    $variabile = 4;
    $session->set("variableName",$variable); // setter
    if ($session->has("variableName") // to check if the variable exists
    {
        $variableName = $session->get("variableName"); // getter
    }
}
```

This is an example; the "variableName" could be accessed next time the same session will be called, if the lifetime of the session is not yet expired.

The "session" uses the __SESSION variable of PHP, so be sure to set correctly the session.cookie_lifetime and session.gc_maxlifetime, in order to give the desired lifetime.

Comment: Session is not a cache! Do not abuse it. Use a file or memory cache instead, e.g. filesystem, memcache, reds etc