# In Symfony 2, is there a good way to interact with the app/cache cache using read() and write() methods?

Tags: caching, symfony

I want to save data to Symfony's file cache. Is there a good way to interact with the app/cache cache using read() and write() methods?

EDIT

The excellent [winzou CacheBundle](https://github.com/winzou/CacheBundle) was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it from the controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException;

//Define your file path based on the cache one
$filename = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.cache_dir') . '/yourapp/filename.txt';

//Create your own folder in the cache directory
$fs = new Filesystem();
try {
    $fs->mkdir(dirname($filename));
} catch (IOException $e) {
    echo "An error occured while creating your directory";
}

//Write your file
file_put_contents($filename, 'Text content');

//Read the content of your file    
echo file_get_contents($filename);
```

Comment: when using the filesystem, you could also do $fs->dumpFile() instead of mkdir and then file_put_contents. more compact and elegant.

Comment: instead of new Filesystem, you could do $this->get('filesystem') to get the filesystem service.

Answer (score 3):

Note that [DoctrineCacheBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCacheBundle) is now recommended. Don't be misled by the Doctrine branding - this is distinct and separate from the ORM and DBAL etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're trying to achieve but you'd have a look at the config component documentation, and specifically at the ConfigCache class:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/index.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/caching.html