# Cache in symfony2

Tags: caching, symfony

I have one table configuration_variables(name,value). It contains configuration variables for my symfony-application such as reset-password-link-expiration-time. Since these configuration variables change rarely, I want to cache it in a temporary folder (app/cache is the right place?).

How can I do it in symfony2?

I tried [How to cache in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893081/how-to-cache-in-symfony-2). But I think it is not suitable to my reqiuirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a cache warmer http://blog.servergrove.com/2012/04/18/how-to-create-a-cache-warmer-in-symfony2/ to cache the configuration in a file. You could use http://php.net/manual/fr/function.var-export.php to export the data to the file, or serialize.

Then, create a service that uses the data from the file.

Answer (score -2):

For such small things you should think about using [Redis](http://redis.io/) for your needs. Saving such data in files is bad habit, and Redis offers you great speed for working with data storage.

> Redis is an open source, advanced key-value store. It is often referred to as a data structure server since keys can contain strings, hashes, lists, sets and sorted sets.

You can also use [SncRedisBundle](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle) in pair with it.

Comment: Did you just seriously recommend a **separate database** for caching project configuration parameters?

Comment: @Inori your downvote is not objective - I recommended implementation of data, which should be rarely changed but often accessed. Storing this data as cache is bad idea. :\

Comment: so you're storing Symfony2 configuration like parameters.ini in Redis?

Comment: I don't think storing data in file is bad practice. Most of the application level caching mechanisms are using files for storing data. I don't want to use database for the sake of speed.