# Variable bound to whole application through requests

Tags: symfony, scope

I want a variable bound to the application scope, (in java that would be application scope).

I thought service should be the thing to use in order to reach my goal.

I created a service test

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Service;

class test {

    public $count;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->count = 0;
    }

    public function addCount() {
        $this->count++;
    }

}
```

which I declared in services.yml

```
acme.my.service.test:
      class: Acme\MyBundle\Service\test
```

I call it in my controller

```
public function testAction() {
        $this->get('acme.my.service.test')->addCount();
        return $this->render('AcmeMyBundle:Test:test.html.twig');
    }
```

But when I retrieve it in my twig, the value is 1, no matter how much I refresh or go with multiple session on the url bound to my testAction.
=> It means that constructor is called each time.

So is that the right way to do? I thought services were created once and reused then, but I may be mistaken.

Could you please enlighten me?

Thank you,
copndz

Comment: service are [stateless](https://igor.io/2013/03/31/stateless-services.html), "reused" means that you always retrieves the same instance from the DIC

Comment: if it's stateless, it's not the same instance then, is it?

Comment: Have you tried saving the count to the user's session? Or to a database if the counter is used across users.

Comment: I'm going for the DB solution since it's cross user. But I thought there would be a more elegant way. (you can post this as an answer if you want me to validate it)

Comment: I'd like to point out that PHP is stateless by nature in the sense that every time a new request comes in, the web server starts the PHP interpreter, which interprets your code and then spits some html out. It is the developer's responsibility to persist the relevant data between the requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was looking for, APC caching system.
Easy to use and integrated to doctrine common.

[How to cache in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893081/how-to-cache-in-symfony-2)

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html