# Symfony 2 : How to clear specific parts of Doctrine APC Cache?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, apc

I am using Symfony 2.3 for my application. As suggested in this topic : [How to cache in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893081/how-to-cache-in-symfony-2/8900283#8900283)
I am using the Doctrine APC Cache from Doctrine Commons package. I understand how to use it then, to store data. For my application, I am using it to store translations of strings coming from my Database, in order to reduce DB transactions useless usages.

However, let's suppose that I want to update this translation. I'd like then to clear the related data in cache, related to this translation, in order to update it to the cache. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->get('cache')->delete($cachedKey);
```

does not works ?

Comment: Indeed, it was what I searched for. I didn't look at the sources of Doctrine Cache. This works ! Thank you.